# How is the Braintree "Transparent Redirect" implemented?

Tags: javascript, http-headers, payment-gateway, meta-tags, braintree

In Braintree's *Step 2* of [How Transparent Redirect Works](https://www.braintreepayments.com/developers/api-overview) they state:

> The payment gateway then stores the data and redirects the customer back to the your site. Because the payment gateway redirects the customer back to your site without displaying any content, the customer won't notice that he or she ever left your site.

How exactly is this **transparent redirect** implemented?

- HTML Meta refresh?
- Javascript load URL snippet?
- HTTP 3xx redirect?

Comment: Isn't this something to ask on their support? I'd believe a `location` header is very appropriate in this case.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, I thought of that, but figured it might be more conversational to ask it here. I'm also interested in using Braintree, so I thought wouldn't it be cool if a someone from Braintree answers my question. I wasn't disappointed. I think this reflects well on the company.

Comment: I asked this question here because I'm interested at a technical level. We currently use Authorize.net's transparent redirect. However, their solution is very crappy. They send a small HTML page with an old school meta-refresh tag and a load-URL Javascript snippet. This actually loads a blank white page on the client for a second or more, depending on the connection. I'm pleased to see Braintree doesn't do this nonsense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a developer at Braintree.

We currently implement this using an HTTP redirect. Merchants configure a form to post to us by setting the form `action` to a Braintree URL.

When we receive the form post, we redirect the user back to the merchant's site without displaying any content. We do this via an `HTTP 3xx` response with a `Location` header.

Unless users are looking at their browser status bar, they won't have any visible indication that they left the merchant's website. This gives merchants control over the user experience of the checkout process without needing to have credit card data pass through their servers.

You can also read an [overview of our Transparent Redirect API](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/deprecated/transparent-redirect/create-transaction) on our web site.

Comment: Just for completeness, I'm assuming a *303 "See Other"* status is used.

Comment: @dan-manges, there's no mention of the Transparent Redirect API on the link in your answer.

Comment: I don't think the transparent redirect API exists any more

Comment: @arcanine, it does exist. I just asked support if it has been EOL'ed and I got this reply: "Although transparent redirect is a deprecated way of integrating with Braintree, it will still work. We do have many legacy merchants that are still using TR for their integration and we currently have no plans to stop supporting this integration method. If this were ever to be the case, we would definitely notify our merchants in advance."